# How to hot reload Typescript Lambda with localstack

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, localstack

I am new to AWS world and working on writing lambdas functions with Typescript. Is there a way to use localstack for development where TS can be hot reloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi — Here is a simple `Hello World!` TypeScript Lambda function in the `index.ts` file:

```
import { Context, APIGatewayProxyResult, APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  console.log(`Event: ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`);
  console.log(`Context: ${JSON.stringify(context, null, 2)}`);
  return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
          message: 'Hello World!',
      }),
   };
};
```

Create a new Node.js project with npm or a package manager of your choice.

```
npm init -y
```

Add the `@types/aws-lambda` and `esbuild` packages as development dependencies.

```
npm install -D @types/aws-lambda esbuild
```

Add a build script to the `package.json` file:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild index.ts --bundle --minify --sourcemap --platform=node --target=es2020 --outfile=dist/index.js"
  },
```

Build the package:

```bash
npm run build
```

Start LocalStack and create a new Lambda function with the `hot-reload` magic S3 bucket:

```bash
awslocal lambda create-function \
    --function-name hello-world \
    --runtime "nodejs16.x" \
    --role arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-ex \
    --code S3Bucket="hot-reload",S3Key="$(PWD)/dist" \
    --handler index.handler
```

Run the Lambda function:

```
awslocal lambda invoke \
    --function-name hello-world \
    --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
    --payload '{"action": "test"}' output.txt
```

Check the `output.txt` file:

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":"{\"message\":\"Hello World!\"}"}
```

Change the `Hello World!` message to `Hello LocalStack!` and run `npm run build`. Trigger the Lambda once again. You will see the following in the `output.txt` file:

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":"{\"message\":\"Hello LocalStack!\"}"}
```

I hope this resolves your query!